# ¿Es posible crear un solo login para multibles tablas en Laravel, es decir diferentes modelos?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Soy nuevo en el mundo de Laravel y estoy haciendo una aplicación donde tengo 3 modelos direntes, con sus respectivos controladores y migraciones, he querido crear un login que dependiendo el tipo de usuario me redireccione a otras vistas, tengo 3 tablas (modelos) diferentes porque cada usuario tiene campos diferentes en la BD, quiero saber si es posible crear un solo login para todos, porque he estado investigando y solo que crean varios login para cada tipo de usuario diferente.

Comment: Supongo que para hacer un solo login para todos, tendrías o bien que validar el usuario con todos los modelos cada vez hasta encontrar uno que coincida (mala idea), o bien tener un modelo compartido y luego sus correspondientes modelos con el resto de campos

Comment: En eso estaba pensando, usar el modelo users y crear otros modelos que hereden de ese. Muchas Gracias